# The type of a User Defined Control

Tags: c#, webforms

I have a user defined control of type UserControls_Name.  (That's the name of the class) and want to identify it as such in the code.

However this always evaluates to false:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(control.GetType(), typeof(UserControls_Name));
```

This occurs within a foreach loop and 'control' is of type ControlCollection. When I call GetType() on this control its' name is  UserControls_Name_ascx.  How can get this statement to be true?

EDIT:  The header of the user control is...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Name.ascx.cs"     Inherits="UserControls_Name" %>
```

The class is:

```
public partial class UserControls_Name : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

Comment: Show the ascx code(header) of the user-control and also the signature of the codebehind class.

Comment: This seems to work...

control.GetType().Name == "usercontrols_name_ascx"